# Modrewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to write modrewrite rule for redirecting queries to city-pages: example what i need:

```
/city_name/category/subcategory/...etc
```

redirect to

```
/category/subcategory/...etc/?city=city_name
```

It works fine if I use in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(bucuresti|verona|sofia)/ 
RewriteRule  ^([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$  /$2?region=$1 [R,L]
```

But because there are a lot of cities (3000+), i have tried to write in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(help|contacts|about)/
RewriteRule  ^([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$  /$2?region=$1 [R,L]
```

I just want to redirect all urls that not starts with 'help' or 'contacts' or 'about'.

But now it use only two last parameters. For example,

*/verona/cat/subcat* redirects to */subcat?region=cat*

Please help to improve

Comment: The exact same question was posted some hours ago, nearly word by word...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257233/modrewrite-rule) is the link (now inactive) to the old question.